# Find all solutions to sys. of equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to find all solutions $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$ for the following system of equations

$x^3=y+y^3$  (1)

$y^3=z+z^3$  (2)

$z^3=x+x^3$  (3)

I found that 
$x+y+z=0$ by subtracting (2) and (3) from (1)

From the looks of it and by trial and error I suppose the answer is 
$x=0, y=0, z=0$

I have tried to play around with different substitutions and factoring different combinations of the three equations but to no success.
If anyone could give me a tip or a solution to this problem that would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: $$x=y=z=0$$ is the only solution of your system

Comment: I see. How would one prove that? Thanks beforehand

Comment: $x, y, z$ are reals?

Comment: Yes! x,y,z are reals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume $x, y, z$ are reals.

Easy to see that $x,y,z$ must be all zero or have the same sign.

Suppose $x , y , z \gt 0$ solution. From (1) $x \gt y$ from (2) $y \gt z$ and from (3) $ z \gt x$ therefore $ x \gt x$ contradiction.

Similar for negatives.

Comment: I forgot to mention that complex solution was not relevant! 
Neat solution, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

solving the second equation for $y$ we get $$y=\sqrt[3]{z+z^3}$$ and $$z=\sqrt[3]{x+x^3}$$ and from here we get
$$x^3=\sqrt[3]{\sqrt[3]{x+x^3}+x+x^3}+\sqrt[3]{x+x^3}+x+x^3$$
can you finish?

Comment: Yes, thanks! Nice to see different approaches